# How to create Multi language website in aspx with database

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to create Multi language website in aspx where database store translations? I search many articles but there is not uniq solution.

Anyone have good isea or know any good article?

Comment: Is there are particular reason you do not want to use ASP.NET's built in culture capabilities using resource files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create your own database resource provider. See this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mosessaur/aspnetlocalization02042006165851pm/aspnetlocalization.aspx) is not using a database but is utilizing ASP.NET's built in Localisation features with resource files.

Comment: It is using db. Look at chapter Building a Database Resource Provider

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice article from Rick Strahl about this.

[Creating a Data Driven ASP.NET Localization Resource Provider and Editor](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwdbResourceProvider/)

The article includes a download link to a component you can integrate in your own website. Be aware that integrating Resources into your websites this way has pros and cons:

Pro – You can delegate the maintenance of your resources to your users.

Con – You lose the tight coupling between resources and code.  No strong typed ResourceManager. No compile time check for resource existence.