# Text management in a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

Hy, I developing ASP.Net for some years now and every time (very often) I code a new asp.net application I need to make sure that all the texts (labels, buttons, … ) I use in the Application must be managed and updated by an admin. Therefor I implemented a own simple component, which updates the data to a Strings table in the application database. This method works for me, but it is a bit painstaking each and every element to my DataUpdatingComponent. How are you handling this problem? Do you know any articles or blog entries handling this problem?

Answer (score 2):

As long as your texts belongs to resources you can create a custom resource provider or use already existing providers. Here is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821778/how-to-create-multi-language-website-in-aspx-with-database/3823356#3823356) where this is discussed before.

Answer (score 1):

I think Satellite assemblies is an option u can think of. They are mainly used for managing resources for multiple regions (support globalization and localization for ASP.Net apps) but you can also use it for managing text resources.

Article:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/tipstricks/article.php/c11367

Comment: The best way I found so far on the wen is: http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/02/RESX-file-Web-Editor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found so far on the wen is: blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/02/RESX-file-Web-Editor.aspx